# Ask Contours of constant density for the p-dimensional normal distribution

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

In my applied multivariate statistical analysis textbook, it says: Contours of constant density for the p-dimensional normal distribution are
ellipsoids defined by x such the that

$$\mathbf{(x-\mu)' \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu)=c^2}$$

These ellipsoids are centered at $\mathbf{\mu}$ and have axes $\pm c \sqrt{\lambda_i}\mathbf{e_i}$, where $\mathbf{e_i} = \lambda_i \mathbf{e_i}$ for
i = 1, 2, . . . , p.

My question: I don't understand why the book claims that "have axes $\pm c \sqrt{\lambda_i}\mathbf{e_i}$". I only know the direction of the axis is eigenvectors of $\Sigma^{-1}$ and the half-axis length is $1/\sqrt{\lambda_i}$.

Comment: They mean in this way that the ellipsoid intersects for example at $\pm c \sqrt{\lambda_1}$ the first axis. They should have used the term semi-axes instead of axes.

Comment: I still don't understand.

Comment: See what I mean by the semi-major axis of an ellipse [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-major_and_semi-minor_axes)

Comment: But I think the intersection point should be $1/\sqrt{\lambda_i}\mathbf{e_i}$ since the length of half-axis is $1/\sqrt{\lambda_i}$

Comment: No it is the square root not its the inverse: the bigger the eigenvalue, the most elongated the ellipse in the associated eigenvector direction

Comment: No, I don't think so. Or I am confused. From my another linear algebra textbook, it said clearly: The bigger eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ gives the shorter axis, of half-length $1/ \sqrt{\lambda_1}$ . The smallest eigenvalue gives the greater length

Comment: I think the issue is that you are dealing with $\Sigma^{-1}$ while I am with $\Sigma$: the eigenvalues of one are the inverses of the eigenvalues of the other (whereas the eigenvectors are unchanged) !

Comment: Exactly! Thank you!